# Javascript import fails when using EL (${pageContext.request.contextPath})

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

Below is snippet from a JSP file.
Earlier I had used `scriptlet` `(<%=request.getContextPath()%>)` to populate the context path as shown in `[A]`.
All 3 javascript files were being imported.

```
[A] 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/a.js"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/b.js"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/c.js"></script>
```

I replaced the `contextpath` population using EL(Expression Language) as shown in [B].
I also modified javascript files a.js and c.js and added some functions.
I redeployed my application ear. I see that the new file a.js is reloaded in the browser (IE) cache, but `c.js` remains unchanged.

```
[B] 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/a.js"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/b.js"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/c.js"></script>
```

Why does this happen? I suspect that `javascript` errors in one of these external files (probably `b.js`) is preventing c.js from loading.
Has anyone come across such a scenario. Please reply . Thanks.

Comment: If you navigate to the JS file manually (in your browser) do you see the old or new version of c.js?

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Comment: Hi Friends, I have found the problem. JavaScript file c.js had some compilation problems like missing semi colon etc. After removing those issues, file c.js also gets reloaded in browser. So I would conclude that when EL is used to import javascript files in JSP, compilation checks are performed on each file. This is not true when scriptlets are used.

Comment: I doubt that very much - probably case of caching and then cached flushed after the change to EL. So coincidence.